# Message extension response time

Tags: c#, botframework, sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

On some RND and experiments with my code, i discovered that if my message extension response does not come in 15secs then i'm getting error in my message extension result box. 
I'm using SharePoint online as a back-end which is querying 2000+ items to form a adaptive card for my message extension result window.I'm using caml query to filter results from SharePoint-online list based on the keyword entered in message extension search box, and then binding data to adaptive card.
So is there any approach by which i can speed up the process and get the response within 15 secs, or i can increase the threshold more then 15 secs in bot framework
I'm using bot framework v3 using c#

Comment: In network tab of console its giving error as "Invoke agent action failed with status code: BadGateway"

Comment: If SharePoint list is not updating continuous basis, please check if you cache the data at application level. You might need to invalidate and fetch new records after certain time period.

Comment: @wajeed, i have divided my code in small functionalities and found that getting data from SharePoint and binding it to adaptive card is not taking much time. But I'm fetch user images from AAD and in one request I'm trying to fetch min 50 images from AAD, so that is taking much time, any suggestions on that?

Comment: Try this: Instead of fetching images directly when you receive request for messaging extenstion, instead just pass **https://yourendpoint/profile?id=userId** while constructing cards and fetch the actual profile images when you receive actual fetch request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find it now, but I do recall reading something about there being a short time limit on this, so that MS can enforce a responsive UI, without it being called "slow" because of a 3rd party (like your app).

Here's an alternative design suggestion: When using a Message Extension, it can invoke a Task Module, which is what you're doing now. Then in your Task Module you can return **EITHER** an Adaptive Card **OR** an embedded web view. See [here](With an embedded web view) for more info. In your case, instead of an Adaptive Card, consider switching to the embedded web view and then on your custom web page, you can show the user a nice "loading" screen or animation, while you load the data from SharePoint in a REST call to a backend API.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have firm business requirement to show data in adaptive card only, if i have to show data in web page then in very first place why would i got for bot framework and teams, rather i would simply create web page with search.

Comment: I guess I didn't explain too well, sorry about that. I'm definitely not saying "create a separate web application" or anything like that. What I means is this: when you create an Message Extension, it has the ability to invoke a "Task Module". A Task Module, in this context, is *basically* a popup window inside of Teams. However, there are two options of what you can put into a task module: (a) an adaptive card or (b) a embedded web view (which is an iframe to a web page you're hosting somewhere). So, in short, I'm suggesting you show the *other* option to what a task module can do.

Comment: Have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/create-task-module?tabs=dotnet and then see there's a section on "With an adaptive card" and then the section below is "With an embedded web view"

Comment: I updated the answer, hopefully that makes it more clear

Comment: I know about task module and already implemented in my application for other feature, but adaptive card can't be replaced by task module. Card i have used for specific reason, so that it can be sent to the chat window and everybody in the channel can see it and use some buttons on that card. So again task module can't be option in any case.

Comment: It looks like you're getting a bit confused between all of these components - I'd strongly suggest reading the link I sent. In short, the answer to your original question is that (a) you can't change the default 15 seconds, but (b) you can get around it using the approach I've suggested.

Comment: I completely understand your suggested approach, but my only concern is i would be able to post task module in chat window of teams

Comment: No, you're right, you can't do that, but you could continue to use your adaptive card for that, which you've got already.

I did think of another possible solution for this though - if the data is coming too slowly from SharePoint, have you looked at caching the data somewhere else, that's faster access. 2000 items you could possibly even cache in memory of the bot itself, depending on the situation of your app (how frequently items change, etc.) - it's just a suggestion, depends on your app of course

Answer (score 0):

The Direct Line channel (and some others) do have a limitation of 15 seconds for the request to complete. You should use *proactive messages* to workaround time limitations. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) for more information and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) for a sample.

Realized I should add a bit of clarification. The bot needs to start a new thread so that the bot can return it's response. You could respond with a message saying "working on it" or whatever. Then your results come in a proactive message.

Comment: More info: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/2161#issuecomment-395203623